# How to fetch VPC Flow Logs from external Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, vpc

I am trying to setup ELK to analyze VPC Flow Logs for my clients. VPC Flow Logs has been configured and its being delivered to CloudWatch Logs.

I want to use this log to trigger Lambda function in my AWS Account (not in client's account).

I was going through the below link:

https://logz.io/blog/vpc-flow-log-analysis/

Can someone please help me here?

Answer (score 1):

If you find that you are not able to do this directly then here are a couple of possible alternatives:

1. You could [publish the logs to S3](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/analyzing-vpc-flow-logs-with-amazon-kinesis-firehose-amazon-athena-and-amazon-quicksight/) within the source
   account and have that trigger a Lambda function in the target
   account (see scenario 3 [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/easy-authorization-of-aws-lambda-functions/)).
2. You might be able to do it indirectly via SNS which can trigger a Lambda in a different account (see [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sns.html)).